# Cancancan gem with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sti, cancancan

I am trying to implement `cancancan` gem for a Single Table Inheritance in my rails app. Following is my table structure for STI:

```
User model
Class User < ApplicationRecord
end

Teacher Model
Class Teacher < User
has_many :students, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "teacher_id" 
end

Student Model
class Student < User
belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "teacher_id"
end
```

Following is my ability model:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

   def initialize(user)
    if user.present?
      if user.type == "Student"
        can :manage, Student
      end

      if user.type == "Teacher"
        can :manage, Teacher
      end

      if user.type == "Teacher"
       can :read, Student, coach_id: user.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

> if user.type == "Student"
>    can :manage, Student
>   end

This is used to prevent Teacher from accessing the pages of student.

> if user.type == "Teacher"
>    can :manage, Teacher
>   end

This is used to prevent Student from accessing the pages of teacher.

Now, According to my understanding, the following piece of code should give access to student profile page, which belongs to specific teacher.

```
if user.type == "Teacher"
  can :read, Student, coach_id: user.id
end
```

However, when i try to access the url of the students which to do not belongs to the logged in teacher account, I am still able to access that page. I suppose this page should redirect to the teacher's profile page.

Here is what i have written for the redirection on access denied:

```
  rescue_from CanCan::AccessDenied do | exception |
    redirect_to user.type == "Teacher" ? teacher_profiles_path : stduent_profiles_path, alert: exception.message
  end
```

I hope i am able to explain the entire scenario. But still if you need some extra information, please do let me know.

Any hep will be appreciated. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: The inheritance issue is one that does complicate matters with this gem. Frankly, having faced it, I have veered to wards making `pundit` the gem of choice for authorisation schemes.  Direct and quicker to implement, particularly s complexity arises

Comment: @Jerome Thanks for quick reply. But it would be really great if you could help me with this gem itself.

Comment: Did you add `authorize_resource` in the controller?